# Access variables set inside command substitutions

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable, command-substitution, subshell

I wrote a simple script

```
 #!/bin/bash -x
 selentry=`ls -l / | sort ; ts=${PIPESTATUS[0]}`
 echo $ts
```

but $ts show nothing. How I can display $ts variable, or how I can get exit status code from command in variable?

```
selentry=`ls -l / | sort`
```

Comment: `ts` is not being set because it runs in a subshell. Also, use `$(...)` rather than backticks. It's easier on the eyes and nests better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In:

```
selentry=`ls -l / | sort ; ts=${PIPESTATUS[0]}`
```

same as the more modern:

```
selentry=$(ls -l / | sort ; ts=${PIPESTATUS[0]})
```

The code inside the `$(...)` is run in a subshell environment (in the case of `bash` and shells other than `ksh93`, it's even run in a different shell process). So any modification made to variables in that subshell won't affect the parent shell.

When you do:

```
var=$(cmd)
```

The exit status however of `cmd` is made available in `$?`. That doesn't extend to `$PIPESTATUS` which in the case of:

```
var=$(foo | bar)
```

contains just one value (the exit code of the subshell which here would be the exit status of `bar` (unless the `pipefail` option is on in which case it may be the exit status of `foo` if it's non-zero). It's even worse in `zsh` where the `$pipestatus` array is not affected by assignment commands.

Here, though, if you don't care about the exit status of `sort` (of the subshell), you could do:

```
selentry=$(ls -l / | sort; exit "${PIPESTATUS[0]}")
ts=$?
```

Here, you could also do:

```
exec 3< <(ls -l /) # here ls is started as an asynchronous command
ls_pid=$!
selentry=$(sort <&3)
sort_status=$?
wait "$ls_pid"
exec 3<&- # close that fd 3
ls_status=$?
```

Or even:

```
{
  selentry=$(sort)
  sort_status=$?
  wait "$!"
  ls_status=$?
} < <(ls -l /)
```

On the more general question of having variable assignments survive command substitutions, in `ksh93`, you can use the `${ cmd;}` form of command substitution (`ksh93` doesn't support `$PIPESTATUS`/`$pipestatus` though).

```
var=${
  foo; c1=$?
  bar; c2=$?
}
```

There's no equivalent in other Bourne-like shells, you'd need to pass the data via some other mean like a temporary file:

```
var=$(
  foo; echo "c1=$?" > "$tempfile"
  bar; echo "c2=$?" >> "$tempfile"
)
. "$tempfile"
```

Or here:

```
selentry=$(
  ls -l / | sort
  typeset -p PIPESTATUS | sed '1s/PIPESTATUS/my_&/' > "$tempfile"
}
. "$tempfile"
ls_status=${my_PIPESTATUS[0]}
```